# Return() Not Working While Print() does after building a function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm working with panel data in R and am endeavoring to build a function that returns every user ID where PCA==1. I've largely gotten this to work, with one small problem: it only returns the values when I end the function with print() but does not do so when I end the function with return(). As I want the ids in a vector so I can later subset the data to only include those IDs, that's a problem. Code reflected below - can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

The version that works (but doesn't do what I want):

```
retrievePCA<-function(data) {
  for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]) {
  if (data$PCA[i] == 1) {
    id<-data$CPSIDP[i]
    print(id)
  } 
  }
}

retrievePCA(data)
```

The version that doesn't:

```
retrievePCA<-function(data) {
  for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]) {
  if (data$PCA[i] == 1) {
    id<-data$CPSIDP[i]
    return(id)
  } 
  }
}


vector<-retrievePCA(data)
vector
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. `return` is only ever called once in a function. As soon as the `return` is it, the function exits. Maybe you just want `retrievePCA <- function(data) data$CPSIDP[data$PCA==1]`. no loop necessary

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a simple misunderstanding of what a function and returning from a function does.

Take the small example below

```
f <- function(x){
  x <- x * x
  return x
  x <- x * x
  return x
}
f(2)
[1] 4
```

4 is returned, 8 is not. That is because `return` exits the function returning the specific value. So in your function the function hits the first instance where `PCA[i] == 1` and then exits the function. Instead you should create a vector, list or another alternative and return this instead.

```
retrievePCA<-function(data) {
  ids <- vector('list', nrow(data))
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (data$PCA[i] == 1) {
      ids[[i]] <-data$CPSIDP[i]
    } 
  }
  return unlist(ids)
}
```

However you could just do this in one line

```
data$CPSIDP[data$PCA == 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. :-)